# Why is my standpipe overflowing?

Tags: overflow

I got a brand new top loader washing machine (GE Profile) and while doing a load of wash on the bulk/high water setting, I noticed the standpipe overflowed in my bathroom down stairs.

I had a front loader and never had an overflow issue before. When the front loader and this new top loader drain, the water does come up through the bathroom sink but doesn’t overflow. On the higher water setting though it does overflow.

My standpipe sticks out of the concrete floor and my bathroom sink drain is attached to it. I didn’t Jerry rig it that way, the previous owners did.

My questions are:

- What can I do to get this to stop?
- Do you think there’s a clog?
- Am I going to need to replace the standpipe which would be a nightmare?

[image: Standpipe picture]

Comment: Pictures of the pipes,  would help, but think a partial clog is a good guess or maybe a vent problem.  The drain pipes should be able to handle the discharge of water.

Comment: The top of the pipe needs to be above the washer tub as does the discharge hose.

Comment: Would you please [edit] your title to be a question. As it stands, it doesn't give anybody much of a clue about what they're going to read about. Putting the year in there doesn't help much either.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. As far as my photos some are too large to upload but as you can see the stack pipe just sticks out of the concrete slab and the further down near the floor the previous owner put a pipe that goes to the sink in the bathroom next door. Sink is normal size.

Comment: Nifty, @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact! There's also the option of manually uploading the image to imgur.com (which is the back end that hosts images for SE anyway), then using the "share" links to paste into the question here.

Comment: @FreeMan The real solution would be pretty simple - probably a developer-day of time - for SE to handle some basic compression as part of the upload process. But images are *mostly* used in the non-coding sites - DIY, Photography, Travel, etc. - and in general images are discouraged (for good reason, as they tend to be unnecessary text screen captures) on the primary sites, so this is just a very low priority thing for SE. As opposed to, for example, making arbitrary "design" changes. Just saying.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I got to the "-" and knew where this was headed! ;) `</off-topic>`

Answer (score 2):

You have a slow drain/partial clog, someplace *after* the bathroom sink. With the front loader it wasn't a problem because it used less water. (That is one of the advantages of a front loader over a top loader.) On the top loader with a small or medium load you are OK because the amount of water is comparable to the front loader. But with the top loader and a full load, you have a problem.

The bathroom sink is not directly related. It just happens to be the lowest output location before the clog, so that's where the water comes up. For some people (like me) it is a floor drain. For some it is a toiler. For some it can be the standpipe itself.

The long-term solution is to clear the drain. It is actually easier to clear a totally (or 95%) clogged drain than a typical partially clogged drain, because it is easier to use air pressure to clear the drain. Broadly speaking, your options are the same as almost any drain clog:

- Chemicals - Often work very well, but often don't. Relatively cheap and easy - pour and wait. May not be a great idea if you have a septic tank. The problem is that if the clog is not too bad then the chemical will get past the clog without clearing it.
- Mechanical - Typically this is a snake. There are small hand/portable-drill powered snakes (usually up to ~ 25 feet) but I suspect you will need something bigger (both longer and more powerful). The big machines are *very* effective but take some real work to use effectively and safely.
- Air Pressure - This starts with a plunger, of course, but that doesn't work well if the clog is several feet away. This also includes both Special CO2-cartridge based systems (which are really neat, but limited capacity) and the best trick I've learned in recent years - a good shop vac on blower mode. With CO2 or shop vac you need to plug up any other outputs so that the pressure will go down the drain and not take the easy way out.

Answer (score 0):

If the sink you mentioned is a large enough utility sink, simply move the hose so the water drains into the sink instead of directly to the standpipe.  That will "buffer" the laundry discharge so it can work with the slow drain.

Long-term, you'll want to clear the clog in the drain but this work-around can help in the meantime.

It also looks like your standpipe is missing a trap.  Does it allow sewer gas into the room?  If so, consider re-configuring it with a trap and either a vent or an AAV.

Comment: The trap could, reasonably, be under the floor. Mine is.